# How to get consumed storage percentage for any persistent volume in openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, openshift-client-tools

I am looking for a simple method to get the storage used and storage allocated for a persistent volume dynamically claimed by PVC for any pod. Is there any rest API or `oc` command for the same?

I am new to OpenShift/Kubernetes. As per my investigation, I could not find any such command. `oc adm top` command describes the usage statistics for nodes and pods only.

Comment: The only way that _I'm_ aware of would be something like `oc exec <podname> du /path/to/pv` (I'm on mobile, but this should at least get you in the right direction).

Comment: @WillGordon Is there any way to use `-c` option with `du` command to get total disk usage? Basically I am unable to use child command options. Also `-c` for `oc exec` means container name while `-c` for `du` means total disk usage.

Comment: You're supposed to use a `--` between `oc exec` and your commands (according to `oc exec -h`). Give that a try, and see if that lets you use `-c` for `du`.

Comment: No it didn't work, but I applied one regex that gives me the desired output. Thanks :)

Comment: @himanshu-jindal kindly share the command that you used at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do: `oc rsh podname` to access pod command line and then: `du -c /path/to/pv` or `du -shc /path/to/pv`.